# Ipython zmq fail, ipython notebook fail and import zmq fail

Tags: ipython, fedora, jupyter-notebook, pyzmq

I cannot run ipython notebook. To check I did iptest, got the following error with zmq:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/usr/bin/iptest", line 9, in <module>

    load_entry_point('ipython==2.2.0', 'console_scripts', 'iptest')()

  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 357, in load_entry_point
    return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)

  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2394, in load_entry_point
    return ep.load()

  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2108, in load
    entry = __import__(self.module_name, globals(),globals(), ['__name__'])

  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/testing/iptestcontroller.py", line 31, in <module>

    from .iptest import have, test_group_names as py_test_group_names, test_sections, StreamCapturer

  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/testing/iptest.py", line 155, in <module>
    have['zmq'] = test_for('zmq.pyzmq_version_info', min_zmq, callback=lambda x: x())

  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/testing/iptest.py", line 117, in test_for
    check = import_item(item)

  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/utils/importstring.py", line 42, in import_item
    module = __import__(package, fromlist=[obj])

  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/zmq/__init__.py", line 35, in <module>
    _libzmq = ctypes.CDLL(bundled[0], mode=ctypes.RTLD_GLOBAL)

  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/ctypes/__init__.py", line 360, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)

OSError: /usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/zmq/libzmq.so: undefined symbol: crypto_secretbox_open
```

I have ipython version 2.2.0 and running it with fedora.

Any help would be very much appreciated

Comment: From the error message I would guess that /usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/zmq/libzmq.so is outdated and a leftover from a previous installation. Did you install ipython with pip or with a package manager? What does `ls /usr/lib{,64}/libzmq.so` print?

Comment: I installed ipython with pip install ipython[all].
ls /usr/lib{,64}/libzmq.so prints:
ls: cannot access /usr/lib/libzmq.so: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access /usr/lib64/libzmq.so: No such file or directory

do i need to install something else besides pyzmq?

Comment: No, that should be fine. I would speculate that removing `/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/zmq` and reinstalling pyzmq afterwards will fix this problem.

Comment: I removed `/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/zmq` and reinstalled with pip, but then ipython would not run as if it had been uninstalled too... had to uninstall and reinstall ipython with pip, but now back to same error

Comment: for me pip install -U pyzmq did the trick

Comment: The problem was solved by installing python with anaconda... don't really know how but it did the trick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved by installing anaconda and with it python